# Why the namespace of PHPMailer is "PHPMailer\PHPMailer;" instead of just "PHPMailer"?

Tags: php, phpmailer, php-namespaces

Why the namespace of the library [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php) is this:

```
namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

instead of just this below?

```
namespace PHPMailer;
```

Comment: PSR-0 hangover (Vendorname)?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.nested.php) with the quote below, since the first PHPMailer directory has many files, you need to specify the complete path to the location you need. Since the PHPMailer is inside the PHPMailer project, it seems repetitive but they are references for different things.

> Much like directories and files, PHP namespaces also contain the ability to specify a hierarchy of namespace names. Thus, a namespace name can be defined with sub-levels.

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Sub\Level;

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }

?>
```

> The above example creates constant MyProject\Sub\Level\CONNECT_OK, class MyProject\Sub\Level\Connection and function MyProject\Sub\Level\connect.